# Can I update a single row by maximum id using eloquent/fluent

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following query:

```
$row = Notification::where('from_user_id', '=', Auth::id())
               ->where('to_user_id', 0)->update(['to_user_id' => $obj]);
```

which works but how do I update just ONE row? I was hoping to use maximum id for example  `->max('id')` but I've tried numerous ways of implementing but im having no luck. Or could I use timestamps to distinguish uniqueness?

```
id|from_user_id|to_user_id |created_at|updated_at
1 | 8          | 0         |2015-04-09|2015-04-09
2 | 8          | 0         |2015-04-09|2015-04-09
```

I'm actually iterating through my `$obj` variable and so it changes simply because it's part of an array which is why I only want to update just one of the rows.

Comment: Have you tried the `last()` or `first()` methods before update?

Comment: Yeah i've tried that

Comment: Take a look on my answer below. It's calling the last entry by date and update the `to_user_id` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the last row (based on created_at field):

```
$row = Notification::where('from_user_id', '=', Auth::id())
                ->where('to_user_id', 0)
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->first();
```

And update the `to_user_id` on that row:

```
$row->to_user_id = YOUR_TO_USER_ID;
$row->save();
```

Comment: Thanks Philip. I did `orderBy ('id')` because the rows were inserted in at the same time. Your solution was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the '=' sign on second where clause and update values have to be array type, the query should be

```
    $row = Notification::where('from_user_id', '=', Auth::id())
           ->where('to_user_id','=', 0)->update(array('to_user_id' => $obj));
```

Comment: You don't need to set the `=` sign, and @Markus is passing an array already on the update() method

Comment: the `'='` sign is not necessary and the `[]` is represented as an array. This `[]` array is common syntax in a lot of languages. Your query is exactly the same as mine